# Waiting to initialize untill data is loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, windows-8

I am trying to design a personal app which loads data asynchronously and then displays a grid according to the windows 8.1 store apps.

i'm running into the issue that my ui is trying to execute before my data is loaded.

my current code:

```
(function () {
"use strict";
var asyncInProgress = true;
var groupedItems;
var list;
var observable;
var matches = new WinJS.Binding.List();
var matchGroups = new WinJS.Binding.List();
var BattleGrounds = new WinJS.Binding.List();

list = getData();
initGroups(list);

function initGroups(l) {
    var groupedItems = list.createGrouped(
        function groupKeySelector(item) { return item.group.key; },
        function groupDataSelector(item) { return item.group; }
    );
}

WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
    Observable: WinJS.Class.define(function () {
        this.dispatch = function () {
            this.dispatchEvent("dataReady");
        }
    }),
    getObservable: getObservable,
    items: groupedItems,
    groups: groupedItems.groups,
    getItemReference: getItemReference,
    getItemsFromGroup: getItemsFromGroup,
    resolveGroupReference: resolveGroupReference,
    resolveItemReference: resolveItemReference,
    updateData: updateData,
    getAsyncStatus: getAsyncStatus
});

WinJS.Class.mix(Data.Observable, WinJS.Utilities.eventMixin);
WinJS.Class.mix(Data.Observable, WinJS.Utilities.createEventProperties("dataReady"));

// Provides support for event listeners.
function getObservable() {
    observable = new Data.Observable();
    return observable;
}

// Get a reference for an item, using the group key and item title as a
// unique reference to the item that can be easily serialized.
function getItemReference(item) {
    return [item.group.key, item.title, item.backgroundImage];
}

// This function returns a WinJS.Binding.List containing only the items
// that belong to the provided group.
function getItemsFromGroup(group) {
    return list.createFiltered(function (item) { return item.group.key === group.key; });
}

// Get the unique group corresponding to the provided group key.
function resolveGroupReference(key) {
    return groupedItems.groups.getItemFromKey(key).data;
}

// Get a unique item from the provided string array, which should contain a
// group key and an item title.
function resolveItemReference(reference) {
    for (var i = 0; i < groupedItems.length; i++) {
        var item = groupedItems.getAt(i);
        if (item.group.key === reference[0] && item.title === reference[1]) {
            return item;
        }
    }
}

function updateData() {
    asyncInProgress = true;
    BattleGrounds.splice(0, matches.length);
    BattleGrounds._currentKey = 0;
    groupedItems = null;
    list = getData();
    initGroups(list);
}

function getAsyncStatus() {
    return asyncInProgress;
}

function getData() {
    var darkGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY3B0cPoPAANMAcOba1BlAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    var lightGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY7h4+cp/AAhpA3h+ANDKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
    var mediumGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY5g8dcZ/AAY/AsAlWFQ+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

    var url = 'https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/wvw/matches.json';

    acquireSyndication(url).then(function (response) {

        // Remove any invalid characters from JSONp response.
        var fixedResponse = response.responseText.replace(/\\'/g, "'");
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(fixedResponse);

        jsonObj.wvw_matches.forEach(function (battle) {
            var anet_id = value.wvw_match_id;
            // Create Group
            var matchGroup = {
                key: anet_id,
                title: anet_id
            };

            matchGroups.push(matchGroup);

            // Get Details
            acquireSyndication("https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/wvw/match_details.json?match_id=" + anet_id).then(function (json) {
                var fixedJson = json.responseText.replace(/\\'/g, "'");
                var obj = JSON.parse(fixedJson);
                fixedJson.maps.forEach(function (value) {
                    BattleGrounds.push({
                        group: matchGroup, key: matchGroup.title, title: value.type,
                        subtitle: value.type, map: "eb", description: "NA", content: "NA", "type": value.type,
                        "scores": value.scores, "objectives": value.objectives, "bonuses": value.bonuses, backgroundImage: lightGray
                    });
                });
            }, function (error) {

                var x = error.getAllResponseHeaders();
                var matchGroup = matchGroups[0];

                for (var i = 0; i < matchGroups.length; i++) {
                    flickrPosts.push({
                        group: matchGroups[i], key: matchGroup.title, title: "Error loading",
                        subtitle: "Error", backgroundImage: lightGray, published: "N/A", description: "N/A"
                    });
                }

                asyncInProgress = false;
                observable.dispatch();

            });
        });

    }, function (error) {

        var x = error.getAllResponseHeaders();
        var matchGroup = matchGroups[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < matchGroups.length; i++) {
            flickrPosts.push({
                group: matchGroups[i], key: matchGroup.title, title: "Error loading",
                subtitle: "Error", backgroundImage: lightGray, published: "N/A", description: "N/A"
            });
        }

        asyncInProgress = false;
        observable.dispatch();

    });
    return BattleGrounds;
}

function acquireSyndication(url) {
    return WinJS.xhr({
        url: url,
        headers: { "If-Modified-Since": "Mon, 27 Mar 1972 00:00:00 GMT" }
    });
}
})();
```

This errors out on groups: groupedItems.groups. which says that groups is undefined.
i know this is because the data is still being processed.

How am i going to work around this?
i took a look at the promise object but the entire concept confuses me as i don't know enough about the infrastructure of a windows 8 app.

Comment: use a callback function that executes when the ajax returns.

Comment: which part of my code would i put in there? everything besides the "variable"  declaration and the init? all the other pages use the "data"  object

Comment: yeah everything that relies on the data. or you could make the ajax synchronous so that it holds up execution until it finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your problem is in the `getData()` function - it is not returning your data because it uses asynchronous calls to get the data.  The data is not yet available when it returns.  It appears that that function makes several asynchronous calls to get data (using `acquireSyndication()`).  When those asynchronous functions finish sometime in the future, you then put that data into `matchGroups` and then later into `BattleGrounds` after more calls to `acquireSyndication()`.

What you're doing is quite messy so there isn't a simple fix.  Conceptually, you need to process the BattleGrounds data from the completion handler of the asynchronous code and ALL code that uses it must continue from inside that completion handler, not after the `getData()` call.  You cannot call `getData()` and use it like a synchronous function because it's asynchronous.  This requires asynchronous programming techniques.

If you are doing multiple asynchronous calls and trying to carry out some action after all of them have completed (which I think is what you're doing), then you will need to code specifically for that condition too.  You can either use promises or you can keep a counter of how many ajax calls there are and in each completion function, you increment the counter and see if this is the last one that just completed and, if so, then you can process all the data and continue executing the rest of your code.

I would also suggest that you don't use promises in one part of a function and then completion callbacks in the very next part.  Use one of the other, not a mixture, to keep your code clean.